# Separating data from JSON object (Android)

Tags: android, json

I am trying to separate data of 3 fields from JSON object and set it into a TextView, but it shows data as:

```
      {"Phone":"123"
      ,"Name":"temp"
      ,"Status":"true"}
```

I just want values from table 123, temp, true in the textView so how to separate these 3 fields?

Here is the code:

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);
            user = new Users();
            user.setName(jsonObj.getString("Name"));
            user.setPhone(jsonObj.getString("Phone"));
            user.setStatus(jsonObj.getBoolean("Status"));
            tv.setText(jsonObj.toString());
```

User is the class with get, set methods for Name, Phone & Status.

Comment: Well, `jsonObj.toString()` returns the plain JSON. Use the variables in `User` instead.

Comment: how to show all three variables in textView ? its childish but i am new to Android

Comment: Well I don't know how your `User`-class looks, but use it's `getName()`, etc-method (if there is any). You should really read a book on Java, it seems you have no idea what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done ! by using   java.lang.Stringbuilder,